# Haskell and comprehension lists

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a function that compares two vectors in haskell using comprehension lists. The thing is that I want to add booleans to my final list, but Haskell interprets this code as if x == y, add the element to the list (that's how comprehensive lists works I know). What I want is a list with booleans if the coordinates I'm comparing are true or false.
Is it possible to do this with comprehension lists?

```
igualdad :: Vector -> Vector -> [Bool]
igualdad v1 v2 = [ x == y | x <- xs, y <- ys]
    where xs = vectorToFloatList v1
          ys = vectorToFloatList v2
```

PD: I'm going to use foldr (&&) True with the list that returns igualdad, in order to get the final result that I want.
Thanks.

Comment: THis will return a list of `Bool`s. I'm not really sure what is not working. For two vectors of length *m* and *n*, it will generate a list with *mn* elements.

Comment: Nop, It is only adding items to the lists when x == y and I need it to add false to the list when x /= y

Comment: that is the case here. You can inspect that. It would only add `True`s if you wrote `[x == y | x <- xs, y <- ys, x == y]` (so with a condition at the right end).

Comment: @milverac8: are you sure your vectors contain something else than one value, and are you sure `vectorToFloatList` works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is a list with booleans if the coordinates I'm comparing are `True` or `False`. Is it possible to do this with comprehension lists?

You get such a list. For two `Vector`s *v* and *w* with lengths *m* and *n* respectively, you will get a list with *m×n* elements, such that the item *v<sub>i</sub>* and *w<sub>j</sub>* will be compared in the result list in the element with index *i×m + j*.

If you hwever want a list of length *min(m, n)*, such that the item at index *i* checks if *v<sub>i</sub>* and *w<sub>i</sub>* are the same, then we can make use of [**`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zip):

```
igualdad :: Vector -> Vector -> [Bool]
igualdad v1 v2 = [ x == y | (x, y) <- zip (vectorToFloatList xs) (vectorToFloatList ys)]
```

or with [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) and [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
import Data.Function(on)

igualdad :: Vector -> Vector -> [Bool]
igualdad = on (zipWith (==)) vectorToFloatList
```

or we can make use of the [**`ParallelListComp`** extension [ghc-doc]](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) and run this with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

igualdad :: Vector -> Vector -> [Bool]
igualdad v1 v2 = [ x == y | x <- vectorToFloatList xs | y <- vectorToFloatList ys]
```

> PD: I'm going to use `foldr (&&) True` with the list that returns igualdad.

There exists a function for that already: that is [**`and :: Foldable f => f Bool -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:and). If you however want to check if all the items are the same, you can just use [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all) here:

```
import Data.Function(on)

sameVec :: Vector -> Vector -> Bool
sameVec = on (all (uncurry (==) .) . zip) vectorToFloatList
```